# How to go back to uswsusp and remove swsusp?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, kde, hibernate

My computer freezes regularly when I don't use it, and now I know why: that's because of the suspend (ram or disk) default system. However, suspend and hibernation work perfectly when I use when of this command: s2ram or s2disk.
But it freezes when I use the default menu of KDE/Plasma 5, or when I use a command like systemctl suspend.
I have read this page : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate#swsusp
...but editing /etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module is not enough to deactivate the default swsusp that continues to be used by default... how can I switch?

Best,
Thibaud.

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
Kubuntu, plasmashell 5.18.5
Dell Latitude-7480

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable s2disk instead of swsusp?

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts -v -a pre /lib/systemd/system-sleep
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post /lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

Did you put `resume=/dev/sdXn` pointing to your swap partition on /etc/default/grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line?